# Can one Twitter account lead to every other Twitter account?

Tags: recursion, twitter, data-structures, data-mining

Well, I'm sure all of you are aware of the Wikipedia 'Easter egg' that enables a user to follow every first embedded link in each article to an eventual link to the /Philosophy page.

**Is it possible to connect to every Twitter account in some sort of linked-list-like fashion by starting from just one account that follows at least one other account?**

Ex:

```
@Bob follows @Pete.

@Pete follows @Bob and @Susan.

So, from @Pete, you can get to @Susan through @Bob

etc...
```

*I wasn't sure if this is supposed to be asked on the theoretical computer science SE page or here on SO.*

Comment: No. It only takes only unlinked Twitter account to break the chain. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nobody follows poor old Toby and Toby follows nobody then you could never get to him. (Toby just likes the *idea* of twitter not actually using it) .

Answer (score 1):

'Orphan' accounts (ones that are neither followed nor follow others) would make it impossible for all accounts to be linked.

Even ignoring them, there would still be some 'closed' loops - just like there are in the Wiki Philosophy curiosity/game.

However, it seems you're not the first to wonder about this and there's a good write-up here: http://www.sysomos.com/insidetwitter/sixdegrees/

Comment: That link is great.  Thanks a lot.  I wondered about how the closed loops would harm my chain.  Thanks.